# Symfony 4.4 Form multiselect bootstrap

Tags: symfony, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to change a EntityType form view for something look like: http://davidstutz.de/bootstrap-multiselect/#templates

I make change on my base.html.twig, by adding dependency, I make try bye using code exmaple on this twig file to see if all is fine and it's working.

Now the problem come when I make change on my _form.html.twig or in the Type.php file, actually after all my try I don't see where to make change.

My _form.html.twig

```
  {{ form_start(form) }}
    {{ form_widget(form) }}
    {{ form_widget(form.Service) }}
  <table width=100% cellpadding="10"><tr></tr><tr><td>
    <button class="btn btn-success btn-icon-split">
      <span class="icon text-white-50">
          <i class="fas fa-save"></i>
      </span>
    </button>
  </td>
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

My UtilisateursType.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Form;

use App\Entity\Utilisateurs;
use App\Entity\Services;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

class UtilisateursType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('Nom')
            ->add('Login')
            ->add('PartagePerso')
            ->add('Service', EntityType::class, [
              'class' => Services::class,
              'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $Service) {
                return $Service->createQueryBuilder('u')
                ->orderBy('u.Nom', 'ASC');
              },
              'choice_label' => 'Nom',
              'multiple' => true,
              'expanded' => false,
            ])
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Utilisateurs::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Thank for you help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Symfony will wrapper each field by an html element (`<div>`) and in order to modify this behaviour you have to override it.
see [form_themes](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_themes.html)

first of all create a template eg: template/form/my_custom_entity_service.html.twig

```
{% use 'form_div_layout.html.twig' %}

{% block entity_row %}
        {{ form_label(form) }}
        <table width=100% cellpadding="10">
          <tr>
           <td>
           {{ form_widget(form) }}
           </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
{% endblock %}
```

then call it in your  _form.html.twig

```
{% form_theme form 'form/my_custom_entity_service.html.twig' %}

{{ form_start(form) }}

{{ form_widget(form.Nom) }}
{{ form_widget(form.Login) }}
{{ form_widget(form. PartagePerso) }}
{{ form_widget(form.Service) }}

{{ form_end(form) }}
```

Note: the way you call the form in your code is wrong consider `{{ form_rest(form) }}`